# Where are the start menu customization pictures located on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, desktop-customization

I would like to take some of the images in the red area shown below for personal use. Are they contained in a specific folder, and if so, which one?

[image: Settings App\Personalize\Start Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pictures are hidden in a DLL file. The file is located at `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll`. You'll need a tool called [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to extract the files. To do this:

1. Copy the DLL file to your desktop.
2. Open Resource Hacker and go to `File` and then `Open`.
3. Choose the DLL file on your desktop.
4. The patterns are in the PNG folder.

Unfortunately, these pictures are all just bits and pieces of the wallpaper because some people have longer start screens that require the pattern to repeat over and over.